# Telegraf config file for Jolokia input plugin for Websphere application server monitoring

Tags: websphere, mbeans, telegraf, jolokia

I have setup the Influx-Telegraf-Grafana, and could figure out MBeans for WebLogic easily, however for WebSphere apart from the basic ones [ java.lang:* ], other websphere specifics are not working, or else may be i could not understand the correct way to call them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if anybody has telegraf config file with Websphere MBeans for jolokia plugin, please can you share

Comment: I use [hawtio](http://hawt.io/) to browse the jolokia data, then its much easier to setup in Grafana once I know what references I'm looking for.